# vbo action without selecting row (in other mean all rows)

Tags: views

Is there any option available to apply bulk operation on all rows of views result, which means no need of selecting any rows?

A good example is in GMail's ***Delete all spam messages now*** which deletes all rows (spam mails) without complaining about row selection.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to this is **Enable "Select all items on all pages"** in Bulk operations settings.

[image]

It presents itself as a button to select all items in the view which you select the "select all" checkbox on the current page.

[image]

It's not exactly what you describe, but you're not going to get that without custom code to modify VBO.

Comment: hmm .. will try to implement option in like "force applying to all rows" or "disable row selection"